# Creating a bingo card witout duplicate numbers

Tags: java

I need help with creating a bingo card that has no duplicate number. I'm still a newbie with Java Programming. So far, this is the only idea I came up. I really do appreciate your help guys.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;`
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Exercise {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rd = new Random();       
    int[][] bingo = new int[5][5];
    String title = "B\tI\tN\tG\tO";

    out.print(title);
    for (int i = 0; i < bingo.length; i++) {
        out.println();
        int num = 1;
        for (int idx = 0; idx < bingo[i].length; idx++) {
            if (i == 2 && idx == 2) {
                out.print("X\t");
                continue;
            }
            out.print(rd.nextInt(15)+ num + "\t");
            num += 15;
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: what help you need? Are there any error's/exception in above code?

Comment: There are no errors. It's just that it will display duplicate numbers.

Comment: When I try to run the code. This will come up.
Like this: 
B I N G O
5 26 32 50 61 
1 17 42 55 67 
13 17 X 37 47 
3 22 37 52 69 
12 18 45 60 61 

As you can see, 17 displayed twice.

Comment: you could add all taken numbers to a list and check if the new random number is in list, if it is just get a new random.

Answer (score 2):

Store the numbers that haven't been taken in a list, and then randomly add them to the card. When you add a number, you remove it from the list, so it doesn't get chosen again.

Like this:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
    add(1);
    add(2);
    add(3);
    ...
    add(70);
}};

for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        bingo[x][y] = numbers.get(numbers.remove(new Random().nextInt(numbers.size()));
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You don't have to call both `get()` and `remove()`, `remove()` returns the removed element.

Comment: A set would make more sense than a list wouldn't it? Also, a loop would make more sense to populate it than a hundred manual calls to `add`.

Answer (score 1):

The common way of doing this is to fill a list with all the numbers you want to use and use `Collections.shuffle` to shuffle it.

```
private static class Bingo {

    final int[][] card;

    public Bingo(int size) {
        // Create it.
        card = new int[size][size];
        // Fill it with 1, 2, ... by
        // First create my seed list of all numbers I want.
        List<Integer> seed = new ArrayList<>(size * size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size * size; i++) {
            seed.add(i+1);
        }
        // Shuffle it.
        Collections.shuffle(seed);
        // Fold it into my card.
        for (int i = 0; i < seed.size(); i++) {
            card[i / size][i % size] = seed.get(i);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.deepToString(card);
    }

}

public void test() {
    Bingo bingo = new Bingo(5);
    System.out.println(bingo);
}
```